# Got signal: 11 (Segmentation fault) Mongo DB v4.0.0

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-16.04

I am using AWS t2.micro (1cpu, 1gb ram) and ubuntu 16.04 x86_64.
And getting FATAL error "Got signal: 11 (Segmentation fault)"

Following is the logs took from `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`
`

```
2018-08-02T13:26:47.880+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=3191 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb 64-bit host=ip-172-31-35-166
2018-08-02T13:26:47.881+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.0.0
2018-08-02T13:26:47.881+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 3b07af3d4f471ae89e8186d33bbb1d5259597d51
2018-08-02T13:26:47.881+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
2018-08-02T13:26:47.881+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2018-08-02T13:26:47.881+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2018-08-02T13:26:47.881+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2018-08-02T13:26:47.881+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1604
2018-08-02T13:26:47.881+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2018-08-02T13:26:47.881+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2018-08-02T13:26:47.881+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1", port: 27017 }, processManagement: { timeZoneInfo: "/usr/share/zoneinfo" }, storage: { dbPath: "/var/lib/mongodb", journal: { enabled: true } }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log" } }
2018-08-10T12:03:13.912+0000 F -        [conn5] Invalid access at address: 0x8de
2018-08-10T12:03:13.928+0000 F -        [conn5] Got signal: 11 (Segmentation fault).
 0x557defff3141 0x557defff2359 0x557defff29c6 0x7fe31fe9e390 0x557df022c5ad
----- BEGIN BACKTRACE -----
{"backtrace":[{"b":"557DEDC7B000","o":"2378141","s":"_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo"},{"b":"557DEDC7B000","o":"2377359"},{"b":"557DEDC7B000","o":"23779C6"},{"b":"7FE31FE8D000","o":"11390"},{"b":"557DEDC7B000","o":"25B15AD"}],"processInfo":{ "mongodbVersion" : "4.0.0", "gitVersion" : "3b07af3d4f471ae89e8186d33bbb1d5259597d51", "compiledModules" : [], "uname" : { "sysname" : "Linux", "release" : "4.4.0-1061-aws", "version" : "#70-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 25 21:47:34 UTC 2018", "machine" : "x86_64" }, "somap" : [ { "b" : "557DEDC7B000", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "365C0577E1D4FD5CD19A9455CB05F9122B9CF331" }, { "b" : "7FFF58BDC000", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "7CEE9A2301D990BE864FBA0109FE4291277791AE" }, { "b" : "7FE32129D000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "005BC5E1FF6F66E81E9ED22A15EEF9A155EC2FDA" }, { "b" : "7FE321082000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "6EF73266978476EF9F2FD2CF31E57F4597CB74F8" }, { "b" : "7FE320C3E000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "250E875F74377DFC74DE48BF80CCB237BB4EFF1D" }, { "b" : "7FE3209D5000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "513282AC7EB386E2C0133FD9E1B6B8A0F38B047D" }, { "b" : "7FE3207D1000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "8CC8D0D119B142D839800BFF71FB71E73AEA7BD4" }, { "b" : "7FE3205C9000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "89C34D7A182387D76D5CDA1F7718F5D58824DFB3" }, { "b" : "7FE3202C0000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "DFB85DE42DAFFD09640C8FE377D572DE3E168920" }, { "b" : "7FE3200AA000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "68220AE2C65D65C1B6AAA12FA6765A6EC2F5F434" }, { "b" : "7FE31FE8D000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "CE17E023542265FC11D9BC8F534BB4F070493D30" }, { "b" : "7FE31FAC3000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "B5381A457906D279073822A5CEB24C4BFEF94DDB" }, { "b" : "7FE32150C000", "path" : "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "5D7B6259552275A3C17BD4C3FD05F5A6BF40CAA5" }, { "b" : "7FE31F890000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn.so.11", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "E09D3783AD1D0BBCD3204FA01E4EF6D756E18F57" }, { "b" : "7FE31F674000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librtmp.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "8D1CC1204D6B6D33BD1D2C5A2A0516A2234322CF" }, { "b" : "7FE31F42A000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "DB5180B568097E2A4690A5B40D36BD134C893FEE" }, { "b" : "7FE31F21B000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblber-2.4.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "D3B183C41F02C7CD18F906AAFD19C69C850F1CEB" }, { "b" : "7FE31EFCA000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap_r-2.4.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "DA0EC53E16B3AC6BDC56EAEFE1BFECDDC395FB2E" }, { "b" : "7FE31EDB0000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "8D9BD4CE26E45EF16075C67D5F5EEAFD8B562832" }, { "b" : "7FE31EA80000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "3CE893F6D1382C2C7648DCCB06E71B1C7E0861CC" }, { "b" : "7FE31E84D000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.4", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "B11678F560199547DCF726384EA39153EE0DFABF" }, { "b" : "7FE31E617000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "D6B36C5A463EE0FA84FDD6D5FD3F7726EDB90D54" }, { "b" : "7FE31E397000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "7B3533D5998D20EE1A1BE3F87789B69041E7F620" }, { "b" : "7FE31E0C5000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "16E3DBC6D048145939BB43BBFD7954D27421B00F" }, { "b" : "7FE31DE96000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "AEB4C08FC47F86C475E9D3996DFE5E9B403ACEBF" }, { "b" : "7FE31DC92000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "1E16CB57F699E215A2A8D4EFEF90883BC749B12D" }, { "b" : "7FE31DA87000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "DF3219B89E86920E901BAC4A80AA60F2B6134588" }, { "b" : "7FE31D86C000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsasl2.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "96BCC7EB28D81B1469EED6F24FC083CBD58577BC" }, { "b" : "7FE31D62B000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi.so.3", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "1FE877BE52A424D0636AFD4D35BB330E41D6E0F3" }, { "b" : "7FE31D3C7000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "A0E2D03FF5CF65937F4425D4EFD4D655243809EB" }, { "b" : "7FE31D1B4000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "E07E186694852D8F69459C6AB28A53F8DA3CE3B6" }, { "b" : "7FE31CFB0000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "3364D4BF2113C4E8D17EF533867ECC99A53413D6" }, { "b" : "7FE31CDA7000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimntlm.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "73A8EADBC85860662B24850E71D4AFBE22C33359" }, { "b" : "7FE31CB1D000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.26", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "59E742306A4EA2872E061ECCE92F35FADDA75357" }, { "b" : "7FE31C87B000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasn1.so.8", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "E5C159E415406AE79D21056D752BA949C408B5B1" }, { "b" : "7FE31C648000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhcrypto.so.4", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "7D15576E1F096614D360784E4A01A1F5FAF908C9" }, { "b" : "7FE31C432000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libroken.so.18", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "481DB33C28D88E43DA6BED65E1A7599407D4D818" }, { "b" : "7FE31C22A000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "9D9C958F1F4894AFEF6AECD90D1C430EA29AC34F" }, { "b" : "7FE31C001000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwind.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "57E25072866B2D30CF02EBE7AE623B84F96FA700" }, { "b" : "7FE31BDF2000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimbase.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "F6F1B4E9F89B716C4A0BA5819BDFFAF4A13EFB91" }, { "b" : "7FE31BBA7000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhx509.so.5", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "C60082E3BB78D0D42868D9B359B89BF66CE5A1A7" }, { "b" : "7FE31B8D2000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "D9782BA023CAEC26B15D8676E3A5D07B55E121EF" }, { "b" : "7FE31B69A000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "7BDD51353D50310FFA1587E4AA01B40ABE32D582" } ] }}
 mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x41) [0x557defff3141]
 mongod(+0x2377359) [0x557defff2359]
 mongod(+0x23779C6) [0x557defff29c6]
 libpthread.so.0(+0x11390) [0x7fe31fe9e390]
 mongod(+0x25B15AD) [0x557df022c5ad]
-----  END BACKTRACE  -----
```

`

After searching about the errors on internet. I found that this error is already resolved in v3.6.x. but we getting this error everyday. Could not found a working solution till now.

Comment: Do you notice any pattern for the crash? What query are you trying to do when it crashes?

Comment: there is not fix pattern.

Comment: As of today, MongoDB 4.0.2 is not released yet. Could you specify what you mean by MongoDB 4.0.2? What language are you using? What about the driver version for that language?

Comment: @Kevin Adistambha  sorry , version number is 4.0.1

Comment: Could you confirm that the crashing is still an issue? How about the pattern of the crash? Do you notice it crashed when you're trying to do a certain operation?

Comment: now its fixed by updating version

Comment: have the same issue after upgrading from 2 to 4. nothing changed in the data. We only run a nsize=512 database. Can that be the cause?
preallocating a journal file /disk/mongodbdata/journal/prealloc.0
2019-01-12T23:10:01.696+0100 F -        [initandlisten] Invalid access at address: 0
2019-01-12T23:10:01.707+0100 F -        [initandlisten] Got signal: 11 (Segmentation fault).

Comment: just check all function which is changed in version 4 @GillisHaasnoot

Answer (score 2):

[SOLVED] This is about the breaking change from 3.4 to 3.6.x
Refer to the image attached below:

[image: Reference for Change Log]

So, this says if you start a replica set with --shardsvr before/without adding the node to any Shard, the Segmentation Fault issue comes up.

**To solve this issue**, you will have to remove --shardsvr option from your config file or start MongoDB without this option.

We at our production servers faced this issue for 3 long days and then this issue got solved in seconds by just commenting or --shardsvr option. We don't use Mongo's complete sharded cluster, rather just the replica set.